# Javascript not geting data

Tags: javascript

When I click the button it doesn't alert the data and also doesn't append the image. it doesn't post the data to the script. but when i do only alert("hello"); inside the function it works fine.
Can someone help because i cant seem to fine the reason why.

```js
function send() {
  var username = $("#username").val();
  var password = $("#password").val();
  var dateofbirth = $("#dateofbirth").val();
  var gender = $("#gender").val();
  alert(username);

  $(".result").empty().append("please wait <img src='giphy.gif'/>");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <center>
    <input id="username" class="inputbox" type="text" placeholder=" Enter Your Username" />
    <br />
    <input id="password" class="inputbox" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Password" />
    <br />
    <input id="dateofbirth" class="inputbox" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Date Of Birth" />
    <br />
    <select class="inputbox" id="gender">
      <option>Male </option>
      <option> Female </option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />

    <input id="" class="button" type="button" value="send message" onclick="send();" />
    <br />
    <div class="result">
    </div>
    <br>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The code works just fine assuming jQuery is available on the page you've given it. I took your code and dumped it into a Stack Snippet (just whole-hog, I didn't put the different bits in the different boxes) and it works just fine.

Comment: I would generally suggest putting the scripts you're depending on **first** (e.g., in the above, first jQuery, then your code), but it happens in your particular code that it doesn't matter provided jQuery is done loading before the user clicks the button, since you only use jQuery within the `send` function. Still, but to update that.

Comment: Thaks for the help @T.J.Crowder.